# BarChart mp Android chart x axis not aligning with the graph

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I am trying to align my x axis data with the bars in the bar chart and also enable a scrolling to the left or right.
I tried different methods but none worked. I am getting my x axis label from my TreeMap for every month with year. but It is not aligning with my bars.

```
            val sortedMap: MutableMap<String, Int> = TreeMap(value2)
            val chart = findViewById<BarChart>(R.id.barChart)
            chart.setDrawBarShadow(false)
            chart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true)
            chart.description.isEnabled = false
            chart.setPinchZoom(false)
            chart.setDrawGridBackground(false)
            val labels = ArrayList<String>()
            for ((keys, _) in sortedMap.entries) {
                labels.add(keys)
            }
            val list2 = ArrayList<BarEntry>()
            var i=0
            for ((_, values) in sortedMap.entries) {
                list2.add(BarEntry(i.toFloat(),values.toFloat()))
                i++
            }
            val dataset = BarDataSet(list2, "Legend")
            dataset.colors = ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS.toList()
            val barData = BarData(dataset)
            barData.barWidth = 0.4f;
            chart.data = barData
            chart.xAxis.valueFormatter= IndexAxisValueFormatter(labels)
            chart.xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
            chart.axisLeft.axisMinimum = 0f
            chart.axisRight.axisMinimum = 0f
            chart.axisRight.setDrawLabels(false)
            chart.legend.isEnabled = false
            chart.animateY(500)
            chart.invalidate()
```

How can I align the bar and put a scroll to the left or right so that i can see all the months with year?

Comment: I attempted to replicate the issue by making up a [simple map of data](https://pastebin.com/vtMxt4da) for `sortedMap` and running your code and it [looks normal](https://pasteboard.co/yfiIA7oiW5qd.png)... You should provide a sample data set for `sortedMap` and a picture of what you are seeing and describe a bit more what you want to see.

Comment: I got the solution. thank you so much for your help. I changed the chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum to 3F and its now aligning perfectly with the graph.